# How do I properly unzip a zip with Chinese character that from Windows in OSX?

Tags: windows, macos, encoding, big5

One day I just zipped a file with Chinese character called `周國賢 - 密封罩.flac`, to a zip, using bandizip <s>& designated encoding to `utf-8`.</s>

And then I try to unzip it in my MacbookPro, which is (probably) using Macintosh as encoding. The file unzipped is called `©P∞ÍΩÂ - ±K´ ∏n.flac`, which does not match the above Chinese name.

So, I try to test about the encoding, and found that Macintosh->big5 would return the Macintosh mysterious symbol into Cantonese, but have some unmatching characters: `周衰�璀� - 密封罩.flac`.

I have tried another file: `§˝µ· - ¨ı®ß.ape`: and it actually output the correct name of the file: `王菲 - 紅豆.ape`

So, here is my question: how do I unzip a file that with big5 chinese character properly and without any information loss? <s>Or how do I zip a file correctly to prevent information loss/ incorrect characters?</s> (edit #2: you can use bandizip to zip the file into utf-8 encoding)

BTW, The encoding converter I am using is https://r12a.github.io/apps/encodings/, which could be quite helpful for you to check for encoding. Don't forget to click `change encodings shown`. And I am not the owner of the encoding converter.

edit #1: I have found that the setting in bandizip is wrong...well sorry for the inconvenience caused. Nonetheless, I figure out that `The Unarchiver` in Mac Apple Store can unzip big5 correctly. This can be a workaround, but still I don't know how to unzip big5 characters properly WITHOUT any loss.

Comment: How are you zipping/unzipping the file? Using `unzip` from terminal should work fine leaving the name intact.

Comment: I have double checked my setting, and found that the utf-8 encoding for zipping is unchecked...Right after I checked it, it can now finally unzip correctly, while winrar seems can't set it.